# Could some one help me translate JavaScript stactic property/method to a constructor function?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, static

```
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Alligator extends Animal {}

const jack = new Alligator("jack");
```

class is actually a constructor function:

```
var Animal = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var Alligator = function(name) {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments); // Call parent constructor
}

// Extend the prototype
Alligator.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Alligator.prototype.constructor = Alligator;

var jack = new Alligator("jack");
```

Now I'm wondering how static property/method of a class is loaded behind the scenes. Could someone help me with it? Take the static property for example.

```
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Alligator extends Animal {
   static eat = 'x';
}

Alligator.eat // ==='x'
```

↑↑↑ to a constructor function?

Answer (score 1):

Static properties are just properties on the class expression itself:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Alligator extends Animal {
   static eat;
}

console.log(Alligator.hasOwnProperty('eat'));
```

So to translate it, just assign to the `Alligator` function. Functions, being objects, can have arbitrary key-value pairs assigned to them:

```js
var Animal = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var Alligator = function(name) {
  Animal.apply(this, arguments); // Call parent constructor
}

// Extend the prototype
Alligator.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Alligator.prototype.constructor = Alligator;

Alligator.eat = 'someEatValue';
console.log(Alligator.eat);
```